# Python variable scope and execution

Tags: python

I am executing a python script:

```
exec(open("process.py").read(), globals())
```

Is it possible to make all variables set within "process.py" local to that particular file?

Comment: Just do `import process`?

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Maybe, but if you `import` a file twice, it only runs the file once. It sounds like this `exec` is more along the lines of "run this file now" than "make the things defined in this file available".

Comment: @user2357112: True. Though perhaps `import process` and then running a function defined in it would be both more efficient and less ridiculous than repeatedly `exec`-ing a file.

Answer (score 0):

You could execute the file's contents in a new dict instead of this code's own globals:

```
with open("process.py") as f:
    exec(f.read(), {})
```

This is a weird way to structure a Python program, though. Usually, you'd organize your code into modules and functions instead of `exec`-ing files.

Comment: or, I suppose `globals().copy()` if `process.py` depends on the current globals (yuck)... Of course, mutations of objects still "leak"...